# updatesettings does not work in Handsontable for columns

Tags: handsontable

I'm trying to update column's setting in Handsontable like this:

```
 var newColumnSettings = [{ data: 0, readOnly: true }, { data: 1 }, { data: 2 }, { data: 3 }, { data: 4, readOnly: true }];

 $('#container').handsontable('updateSettings', { columns: newColumnSettings });
```

But it simply does not work and nothing happens, and handsontable still shows the older columns.

Should I do something before or after? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried to rerender the table after your updateSettings?

```
var newColumnSettings = [{ data: 0, readOnly: true }, { data: 1 }, { data: 2 }, { data: 3 }, { data: 4, readOnly: true }];

var ht = $('#container').handsontable('getInstance');
ht.updateSettings({ columns: newColumnSettings });
ht.render();
```

See if that helps